# Kompose & Kubectl wants to fetch images from registry but I wan't to build them locally

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubectl, kompose

I tried to convert my docker-compose to a kompose.yaml file so I can use it with `kubectl apply` to deploy it on kubernetes.

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
    neo4j:
        image: neo4j
        ports:
            - '7474:7474'
            - '7687:7687'
        environment:
            - NEO4J_AUTH=${NEO4J_USERNAME}/${NEO4J_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - neo4j_data:/data
        networks:
            - app_net

    overseen:
        build: ./overseen
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
        environment:
            - NEO4J_USERNAME=${NEO4J_USERNAME}
            - NEO4J_PASSWORD=${NEO4J_PASSWORD}
            - NEO4J_CONNECTION_URI=${NEO4J_CONNECTION_URI}
            - FLASK_APP=${FLASK_APP}
            - FLASK_DEBUG=${FLASK_DEBUG}
        depends_on:
            - neo4j
        networks:
            - app_net

    dashboard:
        build: ./dashboard
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        environment:
            - FLASK_APP_URL=${FLASK_APP_URL}
        depends_on:
            - overseen
        networks:
            - app_net

networks:
    app_net:

volumes:
    neo4j_data:
```

I have to following problems:

- Its trying to fetch the 2 Images from the dockerhub registry
- The Volume doesn't get created (its pending infinity)

I expcted that it builds them local and use them.
I also exptected it creates the volume.

Can someone help me?

Comment: In general, Kubernetes doesn't know about your local Docker image cache. You need to push your images to a registry that is visible to Kubernetes. A common solution is to deploy a docker registry service in your kubernetes cluster.